# How to get the recent items from the JumpList?

Tags: jump-list

I'm using the Windows API Code pack to create a list of recent documents that are displayed in the jump list. It's working nice. I use this code to create entries:

```
JumpTask jumpTask = new JumpTask()
{
  Title = "RecentTest",
  Desciption = "...",
  ...
}

JumpList.AddToRecentCategory(jumpTask);
```

And I can find them and click them, working fine.

However, now I want to read these items and do something with them in my appliation (like show them, or open the last recent on application start).

My problem is: I can't find any information about reading the recent entries. I've tried e.g. this:

```
JumpList list = JumpList.GetJumpList(App.Current);
```

But this always returns a list without any entries.

How can I get the recent items?

Comment: do you have found an answer to your question? I did have a similar problem (and I still do have it): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30619448/c-sharp-get-jumplist-tasks-from-assembly

Comment: @Unknown6656 no, unfortunately not.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much