# C# - Get jumplist tasks from assembly

Tags: c#, windows, taskbar, windows-api-code-pack, jump-list

Is it possible to read all jumplist tasks/entries from an assembly using C#?
I have worked with the *WindowsAPICodePack* before, but I did not find the appropriate methods/classes. 
I have read some articles which stated that it is impossible to read the jumplist tasks associated to an assembly but I personally think that it *is possible* to read these tasks, as Windows (or at least MS Explorer) has to do it all the time.

Thank you in advance

---

**Edit:** I realized that my question was asked rather clumsily (maybe due to the fact, that English is not my first language). I meant the following:

Is it possible to somehow get all jumplist tasks associated with an assembly?
And if it is, how do it using C#?

Example:

I have the assembly `wmp.exe` and I want to read the tasks associated with this assembly (In this case `Vorherige Liste fortsetzen`[eng.: `Resume previous Playlist`] and `Gesamte Musik wiedergeben`[eng.: `Play entire music library`]).
I know that it is possible to include a .xml-file in WPF-applications, which defines the jumplist tasks and the commands being executed when clicked on these tasks.
[image]

Comment: Maybe I'm stupid, but please clarify your question.

Comment: @dr4cul4: I edited my question :) Sorry for any inconvenience, Sir.

Comment: It's now Clear what you want. I'm also intrest in this, but I do not know the answer...  yet.

Comment: Hi there, do any of you found a way to do it?

Comment: @RoyYosef To be honest, I do not remember how I solved this (if at all). Unfortunately, I lost the hard drive on which the project resided, so I am unable to look for my solution :(

Comment: Ohh, thanks for your quick reply! I will continue my searching.

Comment: @RoyYosef
I'm sorry that I could not be able to be of more use to you. I will gladly accept your answer should you be able to find one.

Comment: Hi it's alright, thank you for your kindness.TBH, it's much more difficult than I expected, but it has to be there (somewhere.. :| )